# "No route matches [POST]" error on submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the route:

```
post '/:locale/email/confirm', to: 'pages#email_confirm'
```

Here is the controller action:

```
def email_confirm
  render plain: params[:post].inspect
end
```

I have this form:

```
<%= form_tag(email_confirm_path, method: "post") do %>
  <dl class="cf">
    <dt class="required">Nama</dt>
    <dd><%= text_field_tag(:nama, "", class: 'input_text full') %></dd>
  </dl>
  <!-- More fields -->
  <ul class="form_btn cf">
    <li class="submit"><%= submit_tag("submit data") %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

I get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST]
```

I need to debug from the controller. Can anyone help me?

Comment: did you ran `rake routes` and checked the route for that post is the right one?

Comment: Can you show the complete logs? What route does it not match?

Answer (score 1):

As per the description shared it seems like relative path which you have mentioned in the form is not being generated,

Modify the routes.rb to below mentioned code:

```
post '/:locale/email/confirm', to: 'homes#dashboard', as: :email_confirm
```

Now run

```
rake routes
```

And check if Prefix is coming as "email_confirm"

Answer (score 0):

Add alias to your route, so that rails can generate [name-helper method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers):

```
post '/:locale/email/confirm', to: 'pages#email_confirm' as: "email_comfirm"
```

Then inside your form, you can use `email_confirm_path` helper method.